# Bad: C++# input and output debug

Tags: c++

this is my C++ homework 'debugging problem' it is about I/O. I have debugged many errors. And the program did not report an error, but its result is wrong.
Its result should be this:
Enter a number:2.3456
Enter a number:0.895
The value of x is:+2.346000000
The value of y is:8.95e-001
but my result is:
Enter a number: 2.3456
Enter a number: 0.895
The value of x is:

It did not give me the right x , also y.

I don't know what's wrong with it

my code:

```
    // Debugging problem 

    #include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ios;

#include <iomanip>

using std::setw;
using std::setprecision;
using std::resetiosflags;

double readNum();
double printFormatted( double, double );

int main()
{
   double x, y;

   x = readNum();
   y = readNum();
   printFormatted( x, y );

   return 0;
}

double readNum()
{
   double num = 0;
   double place = 10;

   cout << "Enter a number: ";
 //  num = cin.getline() - '0';
   num = cin.get() - '0';

   while ( cin.peek() != '.' && cin.peek() != '\n' )
    //  num = num * 10 + atof( cin.get() );
     num = num * 10 + static_cast<double>(cin.get());

   while ( cin.peek() != '.' )
   {
      num = num + static_cast< double >
         ( cin.get() ) / place;
      place *= 10;
   }
   cin.ignore();

   return num;
}

double printFormatted( double x, double y )
{
   char buffer[] = "The value of x is: ";

   for ( int i = 0; buffer[ i ] != '\n'; i++ )
      cout.put( buffer[ i ] );

   cout << setw( 12 ) << setprecision( 3 )
        << std::setfill( '0' ) 
        << std::setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint |
           ios::left)
        << x << endl;

 //  cout.write("The value of y is: ");
   char buffe[] = "The value of y is: ";

   for (int i = 0; buffe[i] != '\n'; i++)
       cout.put(buffe[i]);
   cout << resetiosflags( ios::showpoint )
        << setprecision( 2 )
        << std::setiosflags( ios::scientific | ios::right )
        << y << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for ( int i = 0; buffer[ i ] != '\n'; i++ )` -- string literals are not guaranteed to end with `'\n'`. This is reading past the end of the `buffer` array. Change this to `'\0'`. Better yet, just `cout << buffer;` or `cout << "The value of x is: ";`.

Comment: Why are you reading numbers that way instead of `cin >> num`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can remove these lines

```
for ( int i = 0; buffer[ i ] != '\n'; i++ )
      cout.put( buffer[ i ] );
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; buffe[i] != '\n'; i++)
       cout.put(buffe[i]);
```

just write

```
cout << buffer;
```

2. For me `readNum` didn't work as it should. You have to convert ASCII symbol to number everytime. And you need to skip '.' symbol and after read until `cin.peek() != '\n'`.

```
double readNum()
{
   double num = 0;
   double place = 10;

   cout << "Enter a number: ";
   num = cin.get() - '0';

   while ( cin.peek() != '.' && cin.peek() != '\n' ) {
     num = num * 10 + cin.get() - '0';
   }

   if (cin.peek() == '.') {
     cin.get();
   }

   while (cin.peek() != '\n')
   {
      num = num + (cin.get() - '0') / place;
      place *= 10;
   }
   cin.ignore();

   return num;
}
```

3. You use different flags for `cout`, but you forgot that they are not reset.
   You have to save default flags and restore before using.

```
std::ios_base::fmtflags defaultFlags(cout.flags());
cout.flags(defaultFlags);
```

In summary

```
double readNum();
double printFormatted( double, double );

std::ios_base::fmtflags defaultFlags(cout.flags());

int main()
{
   double x, y;

   x = readNum();
   y = readNum();
   printFormatted( x, y );

   return 0;
}

double readNum()
{
   double num = 0;
   double place = 10;

   cout << "Enter a number: ";
   num = cin.get() - '0';

   while ( cin.peek() != '.' && cin.peek() != '\n' ) {
     num = num * 10 + cin.get() - '0';
   }

   if (cin.peek() == '.') {
     cin.get();
   }

   while (cin.peek() != '\n')
   {
      num = num + (cin.get() - '0') / place;
      place *= 10;
   }
   cin.ignore();

   return num;
}


double printFormatted( double x, double y )
{
   char buffer[] = "The value of x is: ";
   cout << buffer
        << setw( 12 ) << setprecision( 3 )
        << std::setfill( '0' )
        << std::setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint |
           ios::left)
        << x << endl;

   cout.flags(defaultFlags);

   char buffe[] = "The value of y is: ";
   cout << buffe
       << resetiosflags( ios::showpoint )
        << setprecision( 2 )
        << std::setiosflags( ios::scientific | ios::right )
        << y << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Enter a number: 2.456
Enter a number: 0.895
The value of x is: 2.4560000000
The value of y is: 8.95e-01
```